# Definition of Divergent Sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence

I tried to check the definition of divergent sequences in many places. All of them define divergent sequence as a sequence which is not convergent.

I wonder if a Cauchy sequence (which is not convergent in a non-complete normed space) is still called a divergent sequence.

Comment: which is not convergent means divergent.

Comment: Even if your space is not complete, many Cauchy sequences do converge !!! For instance the constant ones, but also many others

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a non-complete space and find a Cauchy sequence which does not converge, then by definition yes, this sequence is divergent. Cauchyness has nothing to do with it.